# MySQL (Workbench?) alters my scripts

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am creating a table into my MySQL database with this script, using `MySQL Workbench`:

```
CREATE TABLE `schema`.`Foo` (
  [..],
  `CreationDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdateDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  [..]
);
```

The problem is that at each commit (including `UPDATE` statements), the column `CreationDate` of the impacted rows is modified.

Using `MySQL Workbench`, I reverse engineered the table and get the following creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE `Foo` (
  [..],
  `CreationDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `LastUpdateDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  [..]
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What the f***?

**What kind of configuration within the server can alter my script this way? How can I create my table without these constraints?**

I am using `MySQL Workbench 6.3.8 Build 1228 CE (64 bits) Community` and the server is `5.5.55.0+deb`, running on Debian.

Comment: Because you defined it as `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` if you don't specify a value for the field it will use the current timestamp and update it.  See documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: If you don't provide a default it has to pick one. Explicitly specify what you want the defaults to be instead of making MySQL guess.

Comment: @Cfreak I absolutely not define this. Something (Workbench or MySQL?) is defining this for me... That's the point of my question, how to avoid this?

Comment: @ceejayoz indeed, specifying `NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` seems to fix the issue. Why is MySQL doing this? This is incredibly stupid and dangerous to assume such a choice without warning the user... It should at least fail during the create table or even better fail on insert when no timestamp provided (like all other DBMS -_-)... And why the same choice isn't made for the second timestamp column?

Comment: @fharreau Only one column can have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default. This behavior of picking sensible defaults if you don't specify them is very well documented: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: @ceejayoz You can post your solution as answer if you want to. It fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify a default value, MySQL will pick one for you.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html

In particular, you've hit these (emphasis mine):

> For date and time types other than `TIMESTAMP`, the default is the appropriate “zero” value for the type. **This is also true for `TIMESTAMP`** if the `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system` variable is enabled (see Section 5.1.5, “Server System Variables”). Otherwise, **for the first TIMESTAMP column in a table, the default value is the current date and time**. See Section 11.3, “Date and Time Types”.